# Regex match either one of the two

Tags: javascript, regex

I have two regular expressions shown below:

```
const regex1 = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\[\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lt}A-Za-z0-9\u3000-\u303f\u3040-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff\uff00-\uff9f\u4e00-\u9faf\u3400-\u4dbf\u3130-\u318F\uAC00-\uD7AF]+$/ug

const regex2 = /^[\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lt}A-Za-z0-9\u3000-\u303f\u3040-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff\uff00-\uff9f\u4e00-\u9faf\u3400-\u4dbf\u3130-\u318F\uAC00-\uD7AF]+$/ug
```

My username field has to accept either of the above two. How to put the above two regex in one regex? I tried below with `|`, but it doesn't work. Can you help me?

```
const usernameRegex = /^[\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lt}A-Za-z0-9\u3000-\u303f\u3040-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff\uff00-\uff9f\u4e00-\u9faf\u3400-\u4dbf\u3130-\u318F\uAC00-\uD7AF]|[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\[\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lt}A-Za-z0-9\u3000-\u303f\u3040-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff\uff00-\uff9f\u4e00-\u9faf\u3400-\u4dbf\u3130-\u318F\uAC00-\uD7AF]+$/ug
```

Comment: But why would you need to do that for?

Comment: How did you check it accept or not .. please share your javascript or php code anything you have .. where you have compared its match or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I tried fixing with the help of @esqew's answer.

```
const usernameRegex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\[\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lt}A-Za-z0-9\u3000-\u303f\u3040-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff\uff00-\uff9f\u4e00-\u9faf\u3400-\u4dbf\u3130-\u318F\uAC00-\uD7AF]+|[\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lt}A-Za-z0-9\u3000-\u303f\u3040-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff\uff00-\uff9f\u4e00-\u9faf\u3400-\u4dbf\u3130-\u318F\uAC00-\uD7AF]+)$/ug
```

Answer (score 2):

Encapsulate the combined pattern you’ve got there in parenthesis `()` tokens:

```
const usernameRegex = /^([\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lt}A-Za-z0-9\u3000-\u303f\u3040-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff\uff00-\uff9f\u4e00-\u9faf\u3400-\u4dbf\u3130-\u318F\uAC00-\uD7AF]|[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\[\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lt}A-Za-z0-9\u3000-\u303f\u3040-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff\uff00-\uff9f\u4e00-\u9faf\u3400-\u4dbf\u3130-\u318F\uAC00-\uD7AF]+)$/ug
```

Comment: It is validating only second regex